# mvn deploy VS. mvn install

Tags: maven, azure-devops, command-line-interface, maven-3, maven-plugin

this is seriously bothering me, I have setup 3 profiles in my pom there id's are as follows

dev
qual
prod

when I use the command **mvn -Pdev clean install** I'm able to select whichever profile I specify with the -P option.

But when I use the commmand **mvn deploy -Dqual** I'm not able to build it wrt to the qual environment. what are the options that I should be using to pick a certian proofile while I'm using the deploy command.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the purpose of those profiles? What kind of differences are you controlling by this?

Comment: If you write `mvn -Pqual deploy` the qual profile should be set. But, as @khmarbaise said, check if you really need all those profiles.

Comment: Can you share your project in one drive?

Comment: @khmarbaise -- those profiles are for different enviroment

Comment: That's what I expected. Can you explain in detail for which artifacts etc. you are using the differences ? I assume those a simply different values for keys in property files? For a war file?

Comment: @khmarbaise for database connections and the deployment enviroment is different as the application registration keys and their respective passwords are different for each environment. I'm trying to deploy it on Azure

Comment: If you are already in a cloud environment you should follow the [12 factor conventions](https://12factor.net/) and do not package the configuration inside your application. it should come from a configuration service (etcd/whatever?)...Apart from that: Are you using spring-boot ? Furthermore if you really need to go that way (Which I can't recommend) you can https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin as a temporary solution?